# Ajax file upload with Play 2.0: exists but replace parameter is false

Tags: scala, file-upload, playframework-2.0

I'm implementing Ajax file upload with Valum on the client side and Play! 2.0.4 on the server side. My action method looks like this:

```
  def ajaxup = Action(parse.temporaryFile) { request =>
    try {
      request.body.moveTo(new File("/somepath/foo.jpg"))
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => Logger.error(e.getMessage)
    }
    Ok("File uploaded")
  }
```

The upload works fine, that is, the file is correctly saved under the name `foo.jpg` on `/somepath/`. But it also throws the exception:

```
Path(/somepath/foo.jpg) exists but replace parameter is false
```

How can I avoid that? Do I need set any property on the file I'm creating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you want to overwrite the existing file `/somepath/foo.jpg`.
In case you don't, just check before if that file already exists.

Anyway, the error message already gave you a hint.
Look at the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.1/scala/play/api/libs/Files%24%24TemporaryFile.html) for the `TemporaryFile` case class. The `moveTo` method can have 2 parameters; the second one defaults to `false` and indicates that you want to replace an existing file.

So, in short, instead of

```
request.body.moveTo(new File("/somepath/foo.jpg"))
```

you write

```
request.body.moveTo(new File("/somepath/foo.jpg"), true)
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [moveTo() API doc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.Files%24%24TemporaryFile), to replace the file, you should use:

```
request.body.moveTo(new File("/somepath/foo.jpg"), true)
```